# Static field in base class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Suppose I have a single static field "ShoppingCart" in a Base class. This field is populated from a database.

```
public static Cart { get {
if (cart == null)
   cart = repo.GetCart(userId);
return cart;
}}

public class Process1: MyBase {
  Cart.Name = UserName // do some processing
}
```

How would this work in an MVC app?, suppose 2 people call Process1, would each one have it's own separate instance of Cart (even though it's static?) Or would the second call from (another browser) overwrite instance of Cart of the previous?

Comment: Simple, don't do it. There are not many times you should use static scoped variables this situation included.

Comment: **second call will override**

Comment: No, it will be the same instance

Comment: The implementation is not *thread safe*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what would happen is that the first to hit the *getter* would initialize the whole static field, and the second one may or may not overwrite it initializing it again.

In order to avoid this, you would need to implement basic thread synchronization with `lock` (i.e. `Monitor`):

```
private static readonly object _syncLock = new object();
private static Cart _cart;

public static Cart Cart 
{ 
    get 
    {
        lock(_syncLock) 
        {
            if (_cart == null)
                _cart = repo.GetCart(userId);
        }
        return _cart;

    }
}
```

#### Some comments about your code

Since a static field is shared across all threads, it means that **all** requests will share the same cart in your case.

Because HTTP is a stateless protocol, you should implement your server-side code to be also *stateless*. You should get the cart in a per-request basis based on the associated *user identifier* in a given request and somewhere at the start of it, access your repository and set user's cart to a controller property.

In ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI, this is implemented using *action filters*, which let you do something before and after controller action execution. Here's a good article about the topic published on official ASP.NET site: [Understanding Action Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

Comment: Even that is bad if you look at the code `repo.GetCart(userId);`, it means all users on the site share a common basket.

Comment: This would happen even if each user/browser will create "new Process1()"?. Cart will be shared between user1 Process1() instance and user2 Process1() instance?

Comment: @Igor See my update... it should give a good hint to the OP to refactor the code in the right way........

Comment: @BobSwanson Process != Thread, and I doubt you would create processes in an ASP.NET MVC app. And yes, even if you create many threads yourself, static fields will be exposed with the same data to all of them unless you use `[ThreadStaticAttribute]` on the static class field, but don't use this on ASP.NET MVC, because it's threading model won't work well with thread-static fields.

Comment: So If in my Base class if make Cart NOT static, that means that user1:new Process1() instance will have it's own copy of Cart, and user2:new Process1() will have ITS own copy of Cart. correct?

Comment: Process1 = Class (name)

Comment: @BobSwanson Obviously, non-static fields are per-request

Comment: @BobSwanson Yeah, you're welcome. BTW see my updates because you might need some refactor in your code ;D